# How to remove time from datetime.fromisoformat if not given?

Tags: python, datetime, iso8601

What do I need to do to get the following responses for the different input strings?

```py
date_str = "2020-01-01"
date_obj = datetime.fromisoformat(date_str)
# Output for date_obj: 2023-01-01

date_str = "2020-01-01T20"
date_obj = datetime.fromisoformat(date_str)
# Output for date_obj: 2023-01-01 20:00:00

date_str = "2020-01-01T00:00:00"
date_obj = datetime.fromisoformat(date_str)
# Output for date_obj: 2023-01-01 00:00:00
```

At the moment, I always get the time included in the DateTime object. When no time is set, then it will include 00:00:00.

Comment: `if 'T' not in date_str: date_obj = date_obj.date()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a try/except:

```py
from datetime import datetime, date

for date_str in "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01T20", "2020-01-01T00:00:00":
    try:
        print("date -> ", date.fromisoformat(date_str))
    except ValueError:
        print("datetime --> ", datetime.fromisoformat(date_str))
        
# date ->  2020-01-01
# datetime -->  2020-01-01 20:00:00
# datetime -->  2020-01-01 00:00:00
```

or a check for the date/time separator:

```py
for date_str in "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01T20", "2020-01-01T00:00:00":
    if "T" in date_str or " " in date_str:
        print("datetime --> ", datetime.fromisoformat(date_str))
    else:
        print("date --> ", date.fromisoformat(date_str))
        
# date -->  2020-01-01
# datetime -->  2020-01-01 20:00:00
# datetime -->  2020-01-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
date_obj = datetime.fromisoformat(date_str).date()
```

which gives:

```
2020-01-01
2020-01-01
2020-01-01
```

Comment: Yes, but this does not solve my problem. When a time is given, I want to have the same, but if no time is given it shouldn't included.